# Do SystemClock.sleep or Thread.sleep just stop UI?

Tags: android

I tried this code And Logged. But I thought I can see title text = 0 and then sleep 1 second and see text 1 and sleep and so on... But that was not. When I run this code, I just see text=3 after 4 second sleep. How to understand this? sleep method just stop UI process And don't stop background process?

```
        for (i in 0..3) {
            Log.d("TAG"," i : "+i)
            binding.title.text = "current="+i
            SystemClock.sleep(1000)
            //Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
```

Comment: If you `sleep` the main thread, the UI will surely hang.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sleep function in android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369718/sleep-function-in-android-program)

Comment: I understand only that onCreate has UI Thread. The reason of what I misunderstand is that there is more theads at onCreate including ui thread?

Comment: there's only one thread on app start.  You the programmer are in control of any additional threads.